# Issues with Smartedit in Development environment

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I an using SAP hybris 2105 and having a few issues with Smartedit. Smartedit works fine on localsetup but it does not let me edit in Development or Production environment. I noticed that the below api is not returning all the required components in DEV environment but in local it returns all the components. On Dev it returns only 1 component.

```
/cmswebservices/v1/catalogs/fffContentCatalog/versions/Online/pages/homepage/typerestrictions
```

Response:

```
[{"contentSlotUid":"MiniCartSlot","validComponentTypes":["MiniCartComponent","NavigationComponent"]}]
```

Any suggestions on how to fix or debug as this only happens in DEV.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add **SmartEditConfiguration** for **whitelisted urls** are allowed access to your smartedit site.

Example:

```
UPDATE GenericItem[processor=de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.impex.impl.ConfigPropertyImportProcessor];pk[unique=true]
$smartediturl=$config-domain.smartedit.url

INSERT_UPDATE SmartEditConfiguration;key[unique=true];value
;whiteListedStorefronts;$smartediturl
```

Then under config directory, add **domain.smartedit.url** key and it's value into .properties files.

- local.properties file: `domain.smartedit.url= ["*"]`
- local-dev.properties: `domain.smartedit.url= ["<your_dev_domain>"]`
- local-stg.properties: `domain.smartedit.url= ["<your_stg_domain>"]`
- local-prd.properties: `domain.smartedit.url= ["<your_prd_domain>"]`

Regards.